# WebApi - How to restrict the call base on the certain conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a requirement to switch on/off some of the features for my application.  I am using WebApi and for each feature we have separate controller/class created which contains the WebApi calls for that particular feature.

When any WebApi call comes to controller I want to check the flag in the DB and base on that flag I want to allow/deny the WebApi call. Any suggestions?

Admin can on/off feature anytime (after the deployment also). Below is my sample code.

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/Customer")]
 [Authorize(Roles = "ABC")]
 public class MyController : ApiController
{
[HttpPut]
    [Route("{xyz}/abcd")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "ABC")]
    public async Task<IModel> CreateCust(string username)
    {
}

[HttpPut]
    [Route("{test}/test")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "ABC")]
    public async Task<IModel> UpdateCust(string username)
    {
}
}
```

Thanks,

Pratik

Comment: kind of `Authentication`?

Comment: consider using `DelegatingHandlers`

Comment: and show us your approach

Comment: Use `MessageHandler` in this case. You can modify call using it a bit.

Comment: I added some more details to original question. I am very new to WebApi. I will look into the suggested approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom action filter, and fill `Response` if action is restricted in order to [prevent action execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16822365/web-api-how-to-stop-the-web-pipeline-directly-from-an-onactionexecuting-filter). Use `System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute`:

```
public class RestrictionCheckAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute 
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext) 
    {
        if (IsActionRestricted(actionContext))
        {
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }

    private bool IsActionRestricted(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // Add your restriction check logic here.
    }
}
```

Then decorate actions that need to be checked with that attribute. Of if you need to execute that logic before all actions you can [register global action filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521040/how-to-add-global-asp-net-web-api-filters) through `HttpConfiguration`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own class and inherit from System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute.

Then you need to override OnAuthorization and add in your extra logic there.

```
public class CustomAuth : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);


            // Check if for your database value in here
        }
    }
```

Then instead of `[Authorize(Roles = "ABC")]` you do `[CustomAuth(Roles = "ABC")]`