# MVC ActionFilterAttribute fires all the time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I have the followin attribute.

I need to do:

1. return a message to the browser in the `filterContext.Result` (I suppose it's that place to do it)
2. be able to stop an action being executed

but, after start the debuggind process, the debugger steps inside `OnActionExecuting` method, and I see an error instead of my page. I thought it's gonna be executed before the `SearchItems` method - why that happens ?

```
public class MyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        bool isValid = false; //some logic here

        if (!isValid)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.PaymentRequired;

            filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();

            return;
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

global.asax

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new MyAttribute());
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

controller:

```
public class MainApiController : ApiController
{
    [MyAttribute]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage SearchItems()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? It is not clear (to me) at all. Your code and your description of what is happening all appear to line up.

Comment: Maybe this helps answer your question? [how-to-skip-action-execution-from-an-actionfilter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837180/how-to-skip-action-execution-from-an-actionfilter) or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16822365/web-api-how-to-stop-the-web-pipeline-directly-from-an-onactionexecuting-filter

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an EmptyResult() you should

```
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/YourRedirect");
```

or

```
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/PaymentRequired.cshtml" };
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it turned out there were incorrect namespaces used

instead of

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
```

I used:

```
public class CustomAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (....) {
            var response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "some message");
            actionContext.Response = response;
        }
    }
}
```

now it works as expected.